# How to increase volume in the Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

All, I was trying to increase the volume of speaker for my Moto G2(2nd) phone. I just update it to the OS Android Lollipop.

I had tried the highly recommended APP (Volume+) in the Google Play.
But the app doesn't work in my phone.

Because I found it only works in the Android 2.3. I thought it must some api which works in the Android 2.3 but missing in the Lollipop.

So I want to know Is there any work around to increase volume for the Android Lollipop? Thanks.

Comment: You could try installing auto mods such as Viper4Android. While I know the dev is busy and development is on hold for the time being. Many custom roms use it and it works wonderfully. I do believe the device has to be rooted for it to work. Take a look here. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191223

Comment: In addition to @jer3my: Viper4Android requires your SELinux to be set to permissive. Otherwise it can't process the audio output.

Comment: eh..Big headache...After I read the post..I really don't know what exactly Viper4Android it is .. Could you please tell me more about it . Thanks.